# Rapidly changing large data processing advise

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

My team has the  following dilemma that we need some architectural/resources advise:

Note: Our data is semi-structured

**Over-all Task:**

> We have a semi-large data that we process during the day
>
> - each day this "process" get executed 1-5 times a day
> - each "process" takes anywhere from 30 minutes to 5 hours
> - semi-large data = ~1 million rows
> - each row gets updated anywhere from 1-10 times during the process
>
>   - during this update ALL other rows may change, as we aggregate these rows for UI

**What we are doing currently:**

> - our current system is functional, yet expensive and inconsistent
> - we use SQL db to store all the data and we retrieve/update as process requires

**Unsolved problems and desired goals:**

> - since this processes are user triggered we never know when to scale up/down, which causes  high spikes and Azure doesnt make it easy to do autoscale based on demand without data warehouse which we are wanting to stay away from because of lack of aggregates and other various "buggy" issues
> - because of constant IO to the db we hit 100% of DTU when 1 process begins (we are using Azure P1 DB) which of course will force us to grow even larger if multiple processes start at the same time (which is very likely)
> - yet we understand the cost comes with high compute tasks, we think there is better way to go about this (SQL is about 99% optimized, so much left to do there)
> - We are looking for some tool that can:
> - Process large amount of transactions QUICKLY
> - Can handle constant updates of this large amount of data
> - supports all major aggregations
> - is "reasonably" priced (i know this is an arguable keyword, just take it lightly..)

**Considered:**

> - Apache Spark
> - we don't have ton of experience with HDP so any pros/cons here will certainly be useful (does the use case fit the tool??)
> - ArangoDB
> - seems promising.. Seems fast and has all aggregations we need..
> - Azure Data Warehouse
>
>   - too many various issues we ran into, just didn't work for us.
> - Any GPU-accelerated compute or some other high-end ideas are also welcome.
> - Its hard to try them all and compare which one fits the best, as we have a fully functional system and are required to make adjustments to whichever way we go.
> - Hence, any before hand opinions are welcome, before we pull the trigger.

Comment: Spark has no direct relationship with HDP... Please only use code blocks for code

Comment: You seem bound to Azure. Why compare Arango when Cosmos offers a similar feature set?

Comment: We actually did try out Cosmos (still do use it a little bit in some parts), we are still considering it but even with Cosmos, its not easy to scale based on demand as it forces us to set a consistent RU limit. We have some azure functions/schedulers integrated to trigger autoscale but of course its based on our "estimation" of when the spike happen instead of the actual demand increase.

Comment: @cricket_007 removed code blocks.. apologize for the wrong format

Comment: Thanks. So, I think it's a new feature for Azure, but if you want autoscaling, checkout databricks https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/sizing.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Also in pipeline. Funny you mentioned, we have a call setup with them next week for a demo!